# Remove all local changes recursively

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to remove all uncommitted changes in a git repo. `git checkout -f` seems to do the trick for the top repo, but how do I clean up things in the submodules?

Comment: http://kalyanchakravarthy.net/blog/git-discard-submodule-changes.html suggests `git submodule foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ryan's comment, I ended up with this solution:

```
git reset --hard
git clean -fd
git submodule update --init
git submodule foreach git clean -fd
git submodule foreach git reset --hard
```

which seems to handle added, deleted and modified files, folders and submodules. It feels a bit bad to use two commands, but they didn't seem to cover all cases by themselves.